# Modified items are multiple times in SP search index

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search-results, crawling, crawl-rules, index-reset

I have a problem with sharepoint 2013 search engine. When I change some item, then in search result old record still display, even after re-indexing items. Not all items behave in this way (mostly items, which have a lot of background operations such as workflows etc.).

**Update:**
We have observed, that this happends when item is moved to another folder and incremental crawl is running.
Yes we know, that full crawl can resolve this issue.
But it could appear again.

What we know:

1. The problem appears only when item is moved to another folder (there
   is a metadata update right before item is moved)
2. We are able to remove duplicity from SP engine when we force recrawl the parent item where item was stored before the change

[image]

Comment: whether you have run full crawl or incremental crawl?

Comment: Have you checked if there are errors during the crawl?

Comment: Yes, I did full crawl and incremental crawl.